# Excel Formula Help for Unique Counts in one column if the value of another columns matches what is in a specific cell in a third column

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula in Excel that will count the number of unique IDs in one column if the value of another columns matches what is in a specific cell in a third column.

COLUMN A - Code 1, COLUMN B - ID Number, COLUMN C - Code 2, COLUMN D Number of Unique Firms by Code, COLUMN E - What the formula should return as answers

[image]

Desired Formula - Count the number of unique ID Numbers in B anytime C (Code 2) matches what is in cell A2 (From Column Code 1)
Then do the same for cell A3, A4, etc.

Notes:

1. I am working across multiple Excel sheets and there are close to 200,000 rows, but for simplicity sake I am putting everything in one sheet and only 15 rows on the image.
2. I have Microsoft Home and Student 2019

Comment: How many lookup values (column A)?  The only way to do this is with array formula and that may get too excessive if there are too many.

Answer (score 0):

In `D2` enter this array-formula with `ctrl+shift+enter` and drag down:
`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($C$2:$C$15=$A2,$B$2:$B$15),$B$2:$B$15)>0))`
It counts the number of unique values in B2:B15 where the value in C2:C15 equals the value of code1 in the current row.